# How to store intermediate results from loop iterations correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have nested for-loops and a computationally expensive function that is executed in every iteration of the innermost loop. The function's return value is a floating point number, which is written in a multidimensional numpy array. Since the computing time of the script is very long, I would like to cache the state of the numpy array every time a new value is entered, for the case that the server crashes in the meantime. If the execution of the script is aborted midterm, at its next call the cached numpy array should be loaded automatically and the missing values entered at the correct position.

The following code does just that. Does anyone have suggestions on how to code this elganter/shorter/simpler?

```
import numpy as np
import time
import random
import os
import pickle


def computationally_expensive_task():
    time.sleep(0.25)
    return random.randint(0, 100)

def is_file(file_dir, file_name):
    path = os.path.join(file_dir, file_name)
    return os.path.isfile(path)

def load_file(file_dir, file_name):
    path = os.path.join(file_dir, file_name)
    with open(path, 'rb') as file:
        return pickle.load(file)

def load_files_from_dir(file_dir, file_names):
    files = []
    for file_name in file_names:
        files.append(load_file(file_dir, file_name))
    return files

def remove_file(file_dir, file_name, verbose=0):
    path = os.path.join(file_dir, file_name)
    os.remove(path)
    if verbose==1:
        print('{} has been removed from {}'.format(file_name, file_dir))

def remove_files_from_dir(file_dir, file_names, verbose=0):
    for file_name in file_names:
        remove_file(file_dir, file_name, verbose=verbose)

def save_var(var, file_dir, file_name):
    path = os.path.join(file_dir, file_name)
    with open(path, 'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(var, file)

def save_vars(vars, file_dir, file_names):
    for var, file_name in zip(vars, file_names):
        save_var(var, file_dir, file_name)


#-----------------------------------------------------------
file_dir = r'example_dir'
file_name = 'example_file'
cache_var_names = ['start_idc', 'cached_var']

n_outer_iterations = 5
n_inner_iterations = 5

if is_file(file_dir, cache_var_names[0]): # check if script was aborted midtime at last call
    start_idc, cached_var = load_files_from_dir(file_dir, cache_var_names)
else:
    start_idc = {'i_outer': 0,
                 'i_inner': 0}
    cached_var = np.zeros((n_outer_iterations, n_inner_iterations))

for i_outer in range(start_idc['i_outer'], n_outer_iterations):
    for i_inner in range(start_idc['i_inner'], n_inner_iterations):
        cached_var[i_outer, i_inner] = computationally_expensive_task()
        start_idc['i_inner'] += 1

        save_vars([start_idc, cached_var], file_dir, cache_var_names)

    start_idc['i_inner'] = 0
    start_idc['i_outer'] += 1

results = cached_var

save_var(results, file_dir, file_name)
remove_files_from_dir(file_dir, cache_var_names)
```

Comment: Well, one thing you can do to make it shorter is to remove `pass`es from the code.

Comment: Well, that's true. Done ;)

Comment: Consider asking [CodeReview.SE] instead

Comment: are there parameters passed to `computationally_expensive_task` or is it purely random?

Comment: Parameters are passed. The parameter values change each cycle of the loop.